# Comparing ArrayList with user input

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, compare, user-input

I have been trying to compare the file content with user input. The program is reading from a specific file and it checks against the user's string input. I am having trouble comparing the ArrayList with the user input.

public class btnLoginListener implements Listener
    {

```
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event arg0) 
    {

        //variables for the class
        username = txtUsername.getText();
        password = txtPassword.getText();

        MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.OK);

        try {
            writeFile();
            messageBox.setMessage("Success Writing the File!");
        } catch (IOException x)
        {
            messageBox.setMessage("Something bad happened when writing the file!"); 
        }

        try {
            readFile("in.txt");

        } catch (IOException x)
        {
            messageBox.setMessage("Something bad happened when reading the file!" + x);
        }

        if (username.equals(names))
        {
            messageBox.setMessage("Correct");
        }
        else
        {
            messageBox.setMessage("Wrong");
        }       

        messageBox.open();
    }
}

private static void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException 
{
    //use . to get current directory
    File dir = new File(".");
    File fin = new File(dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + fileName);

    // Construct BufferedReader from FileReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fin));


    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        Collections.addAll(names, line);
    }       

    br.close();
}
```

Comment: `I am having trouble comparing the ArrayList with the user input.` is a bit too vague. Please explain a bit more and if it is an exception, share the stack trace

Comment: Can you explain names where it come from.

Comment: What is the type of names? What is the type of username? I suspect List<String> and String. How could a String be equal to a List<String>? What are you trying to achieve? You'll have to define "comparing" and "check against".

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to check whether an element `exists` in the `list`. If yes, then you need to use `contains` method, [here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) the Javadoc.

So, instead of using `if (username.equals(names))`, you can use `if (names.contains(username))`.

Apart from this, you should make the following changes:

- Don't read the file every time an event is called. As you are reading a static file, you can read it once and store it in an `ArrayList`.
- Make variables `username` and `password` local.
- Remove `writeFile()` call unless it's appending/writing dynamic values on each event.